# Name of this semi historical book involving espers?

Tags: story-identification, novel, history

The city is Berlin. Story starts out around 1925, roughly 13 years before the Soviet Union and America will enter World War II. Life has started to resume for most people around the world. But, the fangs and seeds planted by the first great global conflict are beginning to germinate. Making a complex web of plots and conspiracies. Caught in these threads of deception is an ultra secret police/intelligence agency of the Weimar Republic.

The agency consists of 3 talented individuals with abilities far beyond those of normal humans. One his old man who is a clairvoyant. Other is a young woman whose is a telepath. The last memeber is young man who has the ability to somewhat slow the speed at which the light is reflected off his body. But, he can do that only for a total of 2 minutes a day. They are only contacted and assigned tasks by a middle aged man whom they refer to as "the point man".

The story starts out with the 3 espers being assigned the task to track down and learn the motive of an enigmatic man named Felix Scheer. He was a former Admiral in the Imperial German Navy, a war hero, who earned the tile "man with the strongest light" in the Battle of Jutland. But he disappeared shortly after and has reappeared again and was spotted in Marktredwitz a month ago.

But as they dwell deeper into the case it gets more complicated. The  murder of police captain Paul Anlauf and office Franz Lenck leads to the connections involving the conspiracies surrounding both the KPD and SPD. And with the steady growing of DNVP, the possibilities of threats to not only the Weimar Republic but the entire nation is increasing steadily. The team eventually confronts Felix but he is assassinated in front of them by another esper. But before Felix dies he reveals that he had a vision that another great global conflict is approaching. And that he wished to prevent it but failed. The team then desperately tries to stop such a threat from being unleashed. But, can even a team of espers/psychics stand against the ultimate forces of destiny ?

Comment: Was the admiral actually named "Felix Scheer" or might that be a conflation of admirals Reinhard Scheer and Felix Funke?

Comment: Can you remember when you read the book?

Comment: This question sounds oddly like the back of a book jacket..or is it just me? Interestingly, the last sentence echoes here - https://www.animecornerstore.com/nightraid1931.html

Comment: @Paulie_D not just the last sentence : _"The city is X, Y years before America enters WW2_"; _" first great global conflict are beginning to germinate"_; _"complex web of plots and conspiracies"_; "_ultra-secret intelligence agency"_... Word-for-word copy-paste, that sounds a bit too spot-on to be coincidental. Flagged for further investigation.

Comment: "Fangs and seeds...beginning to germinate"  makes no sense, until one sees it's a misinterpretation of "hydra's teeth" from the above website.

Comment: I read the 'question' and was going to comment that it sounds more like someone plugging a book, it looks like I'm way behind the curve here